# Read more/less on same line with text, without losing href link

Tags: jquery

I want read more / less to go next to the text and not below as it is now, without losing the link and without using p in var content
ie. var content = $ (". aaa" p) .html (); &  $(".aaa p").html(html);

How to do this, I do not find the solution anywhere, something will always be lost .. thanks in advance

```js
  jQuery(function($) {
      var show_char = 280;
      var ellipses = "... ";
      var content = $(".aaa").html(); 

      if (content.length > show_char) {
        var a = content.substr(0, show_char);
        var b = content.substr(show_char - content.length);
        var html = a + "<span class='truncated'>" + ellipses + "</span><span class='truncated' style='display:none'>" + b + "</span><a class='read-more' href='#'>Read more</a>";
        $(".aaa").html(html);
      }

      $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".read-more").text() == "Read more" ? $(".read-more").text("Read less") : $(".read-more").text("Read more") //change here..
        $(".aaa .truncated ").toggle();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa">
  <p><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't looked closely so not sure if it applies here, just want to make sure you know that this exists: `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is** that you dealing with `.html` not a `.text` so your variable `a` has `<p>` at front of it and `b` has `</p>` at end of it and this forced the code to append some unneeded `<p>` tags

In the next example I assumed that you may have multiple `.aaa` elements So I decided to loop through all the `.aaa` elements using `.each`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.aaa').each(function(){
    var show_char = 280;
    var ellipses = "... ";
    var content = $(this).html(); 

    if (content.trim().length > show_char) {
      var a = content.trim().substr(3, show_char); // use 3 to avoid <p>
      var b = content.trim().substr(show_char - content.trim().length).replace('</p>' , '');  // replace the last </p>
      var html = a + "<span class='truncated'>" + ellipses + "</span><span class='truncated' style='display:none'>" + b + "</span><a class='read-more' href='#'>Read more</a>";
      // wrap the a into `<p></p>` then append the read more to it
      $(this).html('<p>' + html  + '</p>'); 
    }
  });

  $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text( ( i , v) => v == "Read more" ? "Read Less" : "Read more"); //change here..
    $(this).closest(".aaa").find(".truncated").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa">
  <p><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>

<div class="aaa">
  <p><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>
```

Always use `.trim()` to avoid any white spaces

Comment: That's great but "Read less" still go down not below..  Can you fix this?

Comment: @ricky Yes its  empty `<p>` added to the second `truncated` span .. I'll see

Comment: @ricky Answer updated .. I believe there're better ways than this but it's working .. the problem was that you dealing with `.html` not a `text` so your variable `a` has `<p>` at front of it and `b` has `</p>` at end of it .. you can use another ways to avoid catching `<p>` and </p> and everything should work fine